# Subfigures giving Error in Report class

Tags: subfloats, subfig

I have the code as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.540cm,bottom=2.540cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace,graphicx,graphics}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{subfigure}{7cm}
\centering\includegraphics[width=7cm]{Figure1.png}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{7cm}
\centering\includegraphics[width=7cm]{Figure2.png}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption line}
\label{Figure1}
\end{figure}
```

I get the error: *! LaTeX Error: Environment subfigure undefined.* I tried `subfigure` it is not working.

Comment: Remove `subfig` and `graphics` packages.

Comment: It gives **! Package floatrow Error: `subcapbesideposition' undefined in families `floatro
w**.`

Comment: The code is missing `\begin{document}...\end{document}` environment. Is the code you are trying complete?

Comment: You can not possibly get a `floatrow` error from the document you have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

- Please, always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which can be compiled as it is.
- Before posting it, please test it to see, if is complete (your is not, missed are `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`) and if it reproduce your problem.
- Packages `subfig` and `subcaption` are not compatible. Remove `subfig`!
- For `[H]` position specifier you should load `float` package, however, avoid it use as much it is possible. Instead it rather use specifiers, which enable floats to float. For example `[ht]˛` or `[htb]` etc.
- For images please use images which are available to any user of this site. Like as is done in MWE below.
- Considering aforementioned, your code fragment becomes

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace,graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{subfigure}{7cm}
\centering\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}%{Figure1.png}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{7cm}
\centering\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}%{Figure2.png}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption line}
\label{Figure1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and works fine. It produce the following result:

[image]